# Finding the MLE of a function when $L'(\theta)$ doesn't depend on $\theta$

Tags: statistics, optimization, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Here's the problem:

Find the MLE of of $\theta$ when $f(x\mid\theta)=(1+x\theta)/2$ for $-1<x<1$, $=0$ otherwise.

$0<\theta<1$

Find the maximum likelihood of $\theta$ and find its exact probability distribution. Is the MLE unbiased? Find its bias and MSE.

So I'm having problems starting this. If I try to do it the usual way -- find $\theta$ to max the function -- $L'(\theta)=x/2$ which doesn't have a max. This is super obvious just from looking at the function (it's linear), but I'm not sure what to do when this way doesn't work. Thoughts?

Edit: 
What I come up with (just by looking at the graph and thinking about it) is that $MLE=0$ if $-1<x<0$ and $MLE=1$ if $0<x<1$, but that seems odd and a strange place to move forward from.

Comment: Since it has a max at any $\theta$, it must be biased.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2821115/321264

Answer (score 2):

Work with:

$$L(\theta\mid-) = \prod_i \frac{(1+x_i\theta)}{2}$$

or equivalently with the log-likelihood:

$$LL(\theta\mid-) = \sum_i \log(1+x_i\theta) - n \log2$$

Your attempt assumes that you have a single observation in which case instead of using calculus think about when the likelihood is maximized by thinking about the cases when $x$ is greater or less than $0$. But, in general, you are likely to have more than one observation.

Comment: My apologies -- the problem states that the "data consists of a single number X".

Comment: Actually, that probably means that the data is univariate but that it has multiple observations. Would that be a valid assumption based on the phrasing used? Then I would know how to do it (I think, following your hint)

Comment: Univariate would be my interpretation although my comment about not being able to estimate $\theta$ with one observation may not be accurate. If you have just one observation then instead of using calculus think about when the likelihood is maximized depending on if $x$ is greater or less than $0$.

Comment: Ok. I added a small edit above a little while ago considering x greater than or less than $0$, but I'm not sure where to proceed from there if I have a piecewise with $\theta=0,1$ depending on x

Comment: The question is asking for the probability mass function of the MLE of $\theta$. Surely, you can compute that based on the fact that the MLE is either $0$ or $1$ depending on the value of $x$. Once you have the pmf you can evaluate its bias and MSE fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

You're working with an endpoint maximum.

If $x>0$, then $\dfrac{1+x\theta}{2}$ increases as $\theta$ increases, so the value of $\theta$ that maximizes this is at the right endpoint: $\theta=1$.  If $x<0$, the similarly it's at the left endpoint: $\theta=0$.

Comment: Thanks Michael (for both your answers). I think I'm going to stop in and see my prof tomorrow -- It's really not clear if he means there is a single observation or that it is univariate (but many observations). Plus, he's a boss, so it's always fun to go see him.