# Maximum Likelihood Question

Tags: statistics, optimization, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

The aim is to find the maximum likelihood estimator for theta. $f(x)$ is given and we can assume that $1\le x\le-1$. I have completed the steps seen in the image, however I am having difficulty differentiating the logarithmic summation.

$$f(x) = \frac 1 2 (1+\theta x)$$
$$ L(\theta \mid x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \frac 1 {2^n}\prod_{i=1}^n(1+\theta x_i)$$
\begin{align}
\ell & = \ln\left[ \frac 1 {2^n}\prod_{i=1}^n(1+\theta x_i) \right] \\[10pt]
& = \ln\frac1{2^n} + \ln\prod_{i=1}^n (1+\theta x_i) \\[10pt]
& = n\ln\frac 1 2  + \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(1+\theta x_i)
\end{align}
$$
\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial\theta} = 0 + \frac{\partial\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(1+\theta x_i)}{\partial\theta}
$$

Thanks in advance! 
[image]

Comment: If $i$ goes from $0$ to $n$ rather than from $1$ to $n$, then you'd have $(1/2)^{n+1}$ rather than $(1/2)^n$.  That doesn't change your bottom line, but it makes me wonder if you intended $1$ rather than $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: There is a possibility of an endpoint maximum.  Notice that the parameter space is given by $-1/2\le\theta\le1/2$, a fact it might not hurt to bear in mind. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy you are correct. That was my mistake it is from 1 not 0.

Comment: However, let's be clear: the $x$ values still run from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/562037/321264

Answer (score 0):

You want linearity of differentiation and the chain rule:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \sum \ln (1 + \theta x_i)}{\partial \theta} &= \sum \frac{1}{1 + \theta x_i} \frac{\partial (1 + \theta x_i)}{\partial \theta} \\
&= \sum \frac{x_i}{1 + \theta x_i} = 0
\end{align}
$$

I can't see a solution to that though... I would use the Newton-Rhapson method.