# How to find maximum likelihood estimator of this pdf?

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

A random sample $X_1,X_2\ldots X_n$ is drawn from a population with pdf
$$f(x|\theta)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\theta x),\quad -1<x<1,-1<\theta<1$$
I know how to find MLE, but I feel confused in this pdf. It is obvious that it is an increasing function in terms of $\theta,$ if hold $x$ fixed. But $\theta$ is strictly less than $1.$ So I have to stop.

Comment: The maximum likelihood will occur at $\theta = -1$, $\theta = +1$, or at  $-1 < \theta < +1$ at which the likelihood function has a stationary point. You need to check all three cases.

Comment: It is only increasing in terms of $\theta$ if $x>0$. If it is strictly increasing or decreasing and the support for $\theta$ is an open interval, then it has no MLE. That's okay. If it is a constant function (when $x=0$) then it has no MLE either.

Comment: For example it seems that if $x_1=+0.3, x_2=-0.5,x_3=+0.1$ then the maximum likelihood estimate is $\hat \theta \approx -0.3065557$.  But for $n>3$ I suspect you may need numerical methods

Comment: $\log \ell (\theta \mid x) = \log(\frac{1}{2} \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1 + \theta x_i))$, 
$\frac{d \log \ell (\theta \mid x)}{d \theta} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i}{1+\theta x_i}$, 
$0 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \prod_{j=1, j \neq i}^{n}(1+ \theta x_j)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+ \theta x_k)}$, 
$0 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \prod_{j=1, j \neq i}^{n}(1+ \theta x_j)$, as the denominator is non-negative. 
each of the $(1 + \theta x_j)$ terms will also be non-negative, but i can't see how you would solve that equation algebraically. @Henry might be right about numerical methods.

Comment: Asked previously at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2821115/321264 and its linked posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is obvious that it is an increasing function in terms of $\theta,$ if hold $x$ fixed.

Wrong, because $x$ can be negative. Let's write the loglikelihood:

$$L(\theta) = \log  \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac12 (1 + \theta x_i)  \\
= - n  \log 2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(1 + \theta x_i) \tag1$$

with the domain $[-1 \le \theta \le 1]$.

(Notice that the values $x_i=0$ do not contribute, so we can exclude them).

Then $L(\theta)$ is differentiable inside $(-1,1)$, its critical points are given by $g_1(\theta)=0$ where

$$ g_1(\theta) \triangleq \frac{\partial L(\theta) }{\partial \theta}= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i}{1 + \theta x_i}=0 \tag2$$

Further

$$ g_2(\theta) = \frac{\partial^2 L(\theta) }{\partial \theta^2}= - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i^2}{(1 + \theta x_i)^2}<0 \tag 3$$

Then we can conclude that $g_1(\theta)=0$ has a single solution in the reals. Let's call it $\theta^*$.

Then the MLE is

$$\theta_{ML} = \begin{cases}
\theta^* & \text{if } -1\le \theta^* \le 1\\
-1 & \text{if } \theta^* < -1\\
1 & \text{if } \theta^* > 1\\
\end{cases} \tag 4
$$

To find $\theta^*$ we must resort to numerical methods. A simple procedure that seems to work is Newton–Raphson:

$$ \theta_{k+1} = \theta_{k} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i}{1 + \theta_k x_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i^2}{(1 + \theta_k x_i)^2}} \tag{5}$$

Starting with $\theta_0=0$, this seems to converge quickly.